# How to remove block of concrete under old toilet

Tags: toilet

After removing a toilet, I have discovered that there is a block of concrete underneath, which needs to be removed before installing the new toilet.

[image: block of concrete under removed old toilet]

What is the best way to get rid of it?
Would some sort of sculpting chisel and heavy hammer work?

Answer (score 1):

If the floor tile is going underneath it, it should come up pretty easy. do use a chisel and hammer and crack from the top only if possible. You may be able to separate it from the flooring in one piece by setting the chisel at the floor and wedging up the chunk, but you may dislodge tile while you are at it although it will not be likely, still possible. Best to try from the top only, the vibration may make the whole piece come loose anyway....

Comment: It looks like it was used to try to keep the toilet steady...

Comment: unfortunately the tiles were around the concrete block, and the block seems part of the concrete below the tiles

Comment: A very peculiar thing to find, to say the least, - take hammer and chisel to it - carefully if preserving the tile, less so if not.

Comment: Then you will need to have at it with a chisel to the side if you are sure it is part of the floor, though it does not seem possible. I am pretty sure it is a separate pour after the fact. the toilet was turned upside down, filled with concrete, something capped it off while it was turned back up and slid out. Or, they just heaped it up, set the toilet over and removed the excess. Either way, to set the toilet while the concrete floor is being poured is unlikely. I can't see how the flange, bolts and toilet could be set on a wet concrete floor.